# E-mail cai na caixa de spam PHP usando layout HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu cadastrei três e-mails no meu banco de dados, porém quando eu envio o e-mail ele cai na caixa de spam.

Eu não sei o que devo fazer para não cair como spam.

No caso o conteúdo do e-mail é um html de e-mail marketing. (contendo fotos e conteúdo escrito em html).

No caso o código é bem simples, eu envio de um formulário o HTML e pego por PHP.

O host utilizado para enviar é: http://hostbase.com/

Não quero uma garantia que o e-mail nunca cairá na caixa de spam, mas sim o por que dele está caindo na caixa de spam.

Isto não é uma pergunta de opinião, mas sim de experiência, então se você não tem nenhuma experiência de por que está acontecendo isto, por favor não responda.

Acredito que não fui na claro na pergunta, então resolvi edita-la.

A pergunta é simples. Por que neste código os e-mails caem como spam? O que eu preciso mudar no código para não cair como spam? O problema de cair como spam, pode ser o layout HTML?

```
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
$arquivo = file_get_contents($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `email` FROM `mailmarketing` ";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo '<table><tr><td>E-mail: </td></tr>';
while ($dados = $query->fetch_array()) {
$destino = $dados['email'];
// É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$nome.' <'.$email.'>';
//$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailPadrao\r\n";
 echo '<tr><td>' . $dados['E-mail'] . '</td><td>';
$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers, "-f$email");
if($enviaremail){
    echo "<b>E-mail enviado com sucesso!</b>";
//echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=index.php'>";
} else {echo "<b>erro ao enviar o e-mail!</b></br>";}
echo "</td></tr>";
}//echo 'Registros encontrados: ' . $query->num_rows;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Felipe, acho que você não entendeu o ponto do colega @SneepSNinjA. A questão é que não importa se é o usuário ou o sistema de filtragem que manda o seu email para a caixa de SPAM. Você não consegue garantir *do seu lado* que a mensagem nunca seja marcada como SPAM. Não é uma atribuição sua/do seu sistema, simples assim. O que você consegue fazer é seguir melhores práticas pra tentar não caracterizar o seu email como SPAM. As suas duas perguntas são um pouco confusas no sentido de que não pedem tais práticas, e sim uma forma de garantir algo para o qual não existem garantias.

Comment: Felipe, uma dica interessante é usar SMTP ou um serviço como o mandrill para os envios, e configurar o dkim e o spf do domínio. Isso muda brutalmente as chances de um e-mail ser considerado spam.

Comment: Usar SMTP é muito interessante, o nosso colega Diego Souza mandou um código do github para enviar e-mails usando SMTP (PHPMailer)

Muito obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, mas acredito que a pergunta se tornou muito mais complexa do que eu imaginava. Eu apenas queria fazer aquele e-mail não cair na caixa de spam.

Porém agora acredito que eu ganhei mais alguns conhecimentos que posso colocar em pratica para um e-mail marketing. Mas o foco não era e-mail marketing, só queria saber por que o e-mail estava caindo na caixa de spam e como poderia consertar.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no Meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3791/post-marcada-como-duplicada-por%C3%A9m-n%C3%A3o-necess%C3%A1riamente-semelhante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sistemas de filtragem de spam são implementados pelos provedores de e-mail dos destinatários, e cada provedor pode fazer de um jeito diferente. Os critérios exatos para classificar um e-mail como spam ou não costumam ser sigilosos, exatamente para que os spammers não aprendam a burlá-los. Além disso, esses critérios se alteram ao longo do tempo seja por causa de atualizações manuais ou automáticas baseados em inteligência artificial e aprendizado de máquina.

Mas, há algumas coisas que claramente fazem com que os seus e-mails tenham uma maior chance de serem detectados como spam:

- O e-mail tem formato HTML.
- O e-mail contém links para sites externos, especialmente se forem links sabidamente com conteúdo promocional.
- O e-mail contém imagens grandes.
- O e-mail contém imagens hospedadas externamente.
- Muitos e-mails semelhantes foram recebidos do mesmo remetente.
- Muitos e-mails semelhantes foram recebidos vindos de múltiplos endereços de e-mails em um curto espaço de tempo.
- O e-mail contém texto com palavras e sentenças normalmente utilizadas para fins propagandícios ou fraudes.
- O nome real do destinário não é mencionado no e-mail.
- O e-mail contém uma grande lista de destinatários, principalmente se estes destinatários não se conheciam anteriormente.
- Muitos e-mails recebidos deste remetente caíram em contas de e-mail inexistentes ou não utilizadas há muito tempo.
- Os e-mails deste remetente já foram denunciados como spam por alguns usuários.
- O e-mail contém um arquivo executável como anexo.
- Respostas enviadas ao e-mail do remetente tem resposta de caixa de e-mail inexistente ou semelhante.
- O e-mail não tem um link para se descadastrar ou foi determinado que este link não funciona adequadamente.
- O destinatário não recebeu nenhum e-mail do remetente previamente, em especial confirmações de cadastro.
- Muitos outros critérios...

Grande parte do trabalho do filtro anti-spam está nas palavras que contém no e-mail. Expressões como "você ganhou um milhão de dólares", "aumente o seu pênis", "emagreça já", "super-promoção", "confira nossas ofertas", "descubra qual é o segredo", "envie este e-mail para dez pessoas", "ganhe mais dinheiro", "veja as fotos da festa", "compre viagra", etc, fazem com que o seu e-mail caia no spam. Além disso, os filtros anti-spam usam algoritmos de inteligência artificial para para aprender novas expressões como essas automaticamente a medida que analisam os e-mails enviados e recebidos.

E por fim, o seu objetivo é enviar e-mail marketing, e boa parte dos filtros de spam foram projetados exatamente para pegar estes e-mails, e o fato de terem pego o seu, é um sinal de que eles funcionaram para o propósito para o qual foram projetados.

Uma forma de fugir destes filtros é quando o e-mail é de fato solicitado pelo usuário, e então vamos focar nestas categorias:

> - O e-mail não tem um link para se descadastrar ou foi determinado que este link não funciona adequadamente.
> - O destinatário não recebeu nenhum e-mail do remetente previamente, em especial confirmações de cadastro.

Então, se o seu site enviou um e-mail de confirmação de cadastro anteriormente e os seus e-mail tiverem um link para o cancelamento do cadastro e o seu sistema respeite o cancelamento, as suas probabilidades de cair no anti-spam diminuem bastante.

Answer (score 2):

Felipe, use o PHP Mailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
Tem alguns recursos que você pode utilizar, autenticação. Isso pode fazer com que evite cair na caixa de Spam.

Baixe os arquivos para seu projeto. Não fique assustado com tantos arquivos. Você vai utilizar apenas o que está no Require do Código.

```php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.seusite.com.br';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'seuemail@seusite.com.br';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Me parece interessante, vou testar aqui e ver se resolve meu problema. Porém ainda não consegui entender o por que o e-mail enviado cai na caixa de spam.

Eu fiquei pensando em duas possibilidades, ou é o servidor ou é o meu código php.

Comment: @FelipeJorge, pode ser por vários fatores já explicados pelos outros colegas. O diagnóstico específico talvez seja difícil de encontrar.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA. Sim, concordo com você. Mas acredito que esse assunto não vem ao caso. O e-mail está caindo no SPAM **deliberadamente** e não porquê o usuário colocou uma regra para que todo e-mail de determinado domínio caia na caixa de SPAM. Obviamente não tem como controlar o servidor de entrada de todos os servidores.

Comment: O PHP Mailer utiliza  autenticação SMTP, além do mais eu queria algum código para diminuir a chance de spam. Utilizando SMTP ajuda em muito o resultado final.  O problema estava no layout HTML.

Sobre o diagnóstico ser difícil de encontrar, não é difícil de encontrar pois em uma linha pequena de códigos e envio para apenas 3 e-mails não é um desafio muito grande.

Answer (score 2):

Quem faz o controle de spam é o servidor/cliente do destinatário do email, você pode resolver se no caso você puder configurar essas contas de emails, se puderes configurar o servidor ou a conta de email.

Agora para que seu email não caia na caixa de spam de terceiros você não tem como controlar.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tiver um conteúdo HTML muito complexo, o google irá colocar como spam aquele conteúdo. No caso o problema não está no PHP e sim no layout html. No caso antes de enviar para várias pessoas, seria interessante testar e ver se o seu layout HTML não cai na caixa de spam. Caso caia, altere o código ou troque o layout.

Eu troquei o

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
```

por:

```
$arquivo = "<html>
<meta charset='UTF-8' /> 
<table width='510'  bgcolor='#fff'>
<tr>
    <td width='500'><b>Nome: </b>$nome</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width='320'><b>E-mail: </b>$email</td>
</tr>   
</table>
</html>";
```

Agora só é preciso mudar o CSS de maneira que fique como um layout de e-mail marketing. Maneirar nas imagens e nos links.

No caso eu não consegui fazer funcionar com nenhum layout de E-mail marketing pego na internet. Mas descobri que o problema está no HTML, conteúdo de mais, CSS em excesso, etc.