# PHP Mail envia email para spam

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou querendo enviar um email usando phpmail, mas ele sempre cai como spam. Tem alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para não cair no spam?

Fiz um código bem simples para testar:

```
mail($email,"Assunto do email","Corpo da mensagem");
```

Comment: Tente enviar autenticado usando phpmailer.

Comment: Use a versão com autenticação SSL

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65198/e-mail-cai-na-caixa-de-spam-php-usando-layout-html

Comment: vou testar aqui o phpmailer

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo o phpmailer já vem com essa atenticação de SSL nativa. Use-a e abuse-a

Comment: Show! Deu certinho, valew pessoal, usei o phpmailer

Comment: só uma duvida, usei em um dominio que tem o certificado SSL e deu certinho, no sem certificado, continua indo para spam. tem como fazer sem o certificado ou terá que contratar o SSL?